# String Date to Date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I am working with a backend that returns me a date string like `2020-05-05 10:19:25.357479+05:30`. How can I convert this to a Date object in swift? According to the backend, the date format they use is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS+|-hh:mm`. But, when I try to use this string in the DateFormatter, I get an error that says - `"Date string does not match format expected by formatter."`

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Seems like you are not specifying the format for the DateFormatter. Can you please post the code snippet where you are trying to perform the conversion ?

Comment: Your date format should be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Function

```
func dateFromString(_ dateString:String,  format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ") -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let tempLocale = dateFormatter.locale  // save locale temporarily
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat =  format//"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = tempLocale // reset the locale

    guard let getdate = date else {
      return nil
    }

    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: getdate)
    return dateString
  }
```

how to use

```
if let dateString = dateFromString("2020-05-05 10:19:25.357479+05:30") {

        print (dateString)
      }
```